# Comparing multiple values and assigning associated variables

Tags: javascript

I have four variables that I need to sort, and based on the result, push associated values to one of two arrays.  Values are dynamic, and can match, but I need an even split in the arrays (2 and 2), ideally with a and b always going to the first array in the event of a tie.

```
var a = 0;
var b = 23.5;
var c = 0;
var d = 96.2;

var ac, bc, cc, dc;

var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
//Here is where Im trying to find the top numbers, and based on the value, push the ac, bc, cc, or dc variables to separate arrays.
((a > b && a > c && a > d) ? (array1.push(ac)): (array2.push(ac)));
((b > a && b > c && b > d) ? (array1.push(bc)): (array2.push(bc)));
((c > a && c > b && c > d) ? (array1.push(cc)): (array2.push(cc)));
((d > a && d > c && d > d) ? (array1.push(dc)): (array2.push(dc)));
```

Obviously this isnt working, as it only finds the highest number of the four.  Is there anyway to do this without writing in every scenario?

Edit:  Just to clarify, Im trying to compare the first set (a, b, c, d) and based on the outcome, sort the second set (ac, bc, cc, dc) into two arrays.  This method works with comparing two variables (a > b) as there are only two outcomes (true/false).

Comment: Put the values in an array and use [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Could you provide an example of expected output?  How are `ac`, `bc`, `cc`, `dc` defined, or does that matter?

Comment: throw those values in an array, loop through the array and compare them or what ever you want to do. And based on which index it is add it to whatever array you want.

Comment: @Pointy .sort() works to determine the largest in the array, but then how could those be used to assign the other variables to two different arrays?

Comment: @RickHitchcock output for ac, bc, cc, and dc is css classes.  Say, .ac, .bc, .cc, .dc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = 0;
var b = 23.5;
var c = 0;
var d = 96.2;

var array1 =
[
    { priority: a, value: ac },
    { priority: b, value: bc },
    { priority: c, value: cc },
    { priority: d, value: dc }
];
array1.sort(function(v1, v2) { return v1.priority - v2.priority; });
var array2 = array1.splice(2, 2); // remove 2 items starting at index 2
```

Now you can refer to the values as `array1[0].value`, etc.

**EDIT**: If you want only the values, you can do this:

```
array2 = array2.map(function(v) { return v.value; });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the trick is that the first variables (a, b, c, and d) are used to sort the second set of variables (ac, bc, cc, dc) into two different arrays.  This works fine with pairs of two (a > b), but anything more than that is the problem.

Comment: Very nice...exactly what I was looking to do.  Thanks!